# How should I free an array in C?

Tags: c, free, calloc

I created a function to free an array in C, but I don't know
whether it is correct or not:

```
void dealloc_array(void *array[], int size) {

         int i = 0;

         for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if (array[i]) free(array[i]);
         }

         if (array) free(array);


}
```

I'm not sure whether I should execute `free(array)` at the end. Technically, we've already freed all the array elements, so we don't need to do `free(array)`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show the memory allocation statements.

Comment: Rule is simple - if you allocate it (1) preserve a pointer to the beginning of the block of memory; so (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. No caveats.

Comment: `array = calloc(size, sizeof(int) * 3);`

Comment: Where `size` is an arbitrary amount.

Comment: Yes, you very much do need to `free(array)`, if `array` was allocated using `malloc` or similar.

Comment: Looks fine, but be careful of dangling pointers. If you delete an element from the array, the pointer in the Array must be set to NULL or you might end up freeing the same block of memory more than once...

Comment: Or you could [use a garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Comment: You do not need to test a pointer before passing it to `free`. `free` is specified to do nothing when passed a null pointer.

Comment: Each call to malloc needs to be matched with a call to free, simple as that.

Comment: `array = calloc(size, sizeof(int) * 3);` What are these parameters supposed to mean? How do you want to use `array`? If you call `free(array[i])` shouldn't there be some pointer type involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you malloc the pointer as well as each element of the array you will need to free that pointer after your for loop.

For example:

```
int **array;
array = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int*));
for(int ii = 0; ii < SIZE; ii++)
{
     array[ii] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

you will have to free each element and free array.
Essentially for every malloc/calloc you have, you must have a free

Comment: Does that go for `calloc()` as well?

Comment: @ssharma: yes it foes for calloc() as well

Comment: yes, calloc allocates memory the same as malloc.
calloc then initialises the memory to zero, whereas malloc does not.
For every malloc OR calloc, you must have a free

Comment: @JoshuaJames: `calloc()` initialises memory to zero while `malloc()` doesn't initialise.

Comment: yes, if the original double pointer was malloc'd. because we cant see your allocation code we cant say.
Please mark answer as correct and useful

Comment: @Destructor thats what i said: "calloc initialises the memory"
edited for clarification

Comment: The original double pointer looked like this: `int **array = calloc(size, sizeof(int));`

Comment: so you did allocate the memory, so you must free it. which means your code is correct. Please mark answer as correct

Comment: Note that the `(int **)malloc...` cast is not only unnecessary but not recommended

Comment: @ssharma as comment to the question you provided totally different allocation code. Please add it to the question and show the **real** code, not some random stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You must write `free(array)` at the end, otherwise there will be memory leak.